# How to convert PHP response to JSON when using FormData()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am making a cURL call in PHP and echoing the response out so that I can receive the response via AJAX. However, when I do it using `FormData()` instead of `serialize()` I cannot seem to get the response to be returned as JSON:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        // This returns a string
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

However, if I use `serialize()` instead of `FormData()` with `dataType: 'json'` it correctly logs out the response in JSON:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
        // this returns JSON
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

I tried adding `dataType: 'json'` to my first code snippet, but when I do that the AJAX call doesn't run at all.

Here's what my PHP looks like:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "Error:" . $err;
} else {
    echo json_decode(json_encode($response));
}
```

Here is an abbreviated example of the response I am getting from the first code snippet. I have formatted it, but in the actual response I am getting one long, unformatted string:

```
{
   "Locale":"en_US",
   "Errors":[
      
   ],
   "FormErrors":{
      "GroupErrors":{
         
      },
      "GroupErrorsOrder":[
         
      ],
      "FieldErrors":{
         "reviewtext":{
            "Field":"reviewtext",
            "Message":"Your review text is too short.",
            "Code":"ERROR_FORM_TOO_SHORT"
         }
      },
      "FieldErrorsOrder":[
         "reviewtext"
      ]
   },
   "AuthorSubmissionToken":null,
   "HasErrors":true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse on the response? ie. JSON.parse(response);

Comment: @Josh Yeah, I tried that but it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: What is the output when you simply log the response?

Comment: @Josh I have added an abbreviated and formatted version of the response I am getting, to the question. The response is currently coming through as a `string`.

Comment: In your php, why is the json_encode wrapped in json_decode? If you echo json_encode($response), you should end up with a json encoded string which can then be parsed by your JS

Comment: @josh that was something I found elsewhere on SO and gave it a shot. If I change it to `echo json_encode($response)` in the PHP and then console log `JSON.parse(response)` in the JS it is still in string format.

Comment: What is in the $response variable? You may need to operate on the response, then build and return an json encoded array from your PHP. I'm guessing JS can't parse the contents of $response

Comment: @Josh Turns out I didn't need to encode/decode at all! Went to echo out `$response` so I could show you an example and that got it working using `JSON.parse`. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem at all! :)